# How do I get a log for submodule ref pointer?

Tags: git, git-submodules

My submodule ref pointer was moved back a few revisions and I would like to know who commited that change to our main repo, how can I do that? How can I get a log just for submodule reference? Because going through every commit searching for changed submodule reference is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check the log for the gitlink representing your submodule in your parent repo:

```
git log -- yourSubmodule
```

No trailing '/' here: `yoursubmodule` is the name of the folder in which your submodule is checked out.
But it is also the name of the [gitlink (special entry `mode 160000`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) recording that submodule in the parent repo.

That will list only the commits in which yoursubmodule gitlink has changed.